# Is true that $n=m$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $O\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ and $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:O\to U$ a bijective  function with $f$ and $f^{-1}$ differentiable in their domains. Is true that $n=m$?
$O$ and $U$ are open.

I don't know how to approach this problem. Any help please!!

Comment: Hint: inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $O$ and $U$ are open then $n=m$ by invariance of domain but this is a bit high powered. Notice that since both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable then:

$f\circ f^{-1}(x)=x$ implies that $I_{n}=Df\circ Df^{-1}$

so $Df$ has a right inverse. A similar computation with $f$ and $f^{-1}$ reversed shows that $Df$ has a left inverse too. Hence, $n=m$.

Comment: I suspect this is the sort of argument the OP was expected to find.

Comment: Thanks i see this more clear now!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad its clear.

Answer (score 2):

If $O$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$, it contains open balls which are $m$-dimensional and so $O$ is $m$-dimensional. Similarly $U$ is $n$-dimensional.

Then your function says $O$ and $U$ are homeomorphic, dimension being a topological invariant, so $n=m$.

Comment: This is very handwavey but I'm pretty sure you could prove the Lebesgue covering dimension of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is $m$, and that's the only thing that really needs spelling out

Comment: How do you define dimension? Why is it a topological invariant? (There would be no need to ask the question if this notion and its properties are known.)

Comment: Considering that differentiability is given here, it seems unlikely that this is the answer OP is looking for

Comment: @AndresCaicedo see my comment if you didn't notice it

Comment: @JohnFernley Yes, it only appeared on my screen after my comment was posted.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo OK cool, you do agree that the result is true without differentiability then?

Comment: @JohnFernley I've never disagreed with it.